# Applying Kinematics to find retarding force in a medium

Tags: forces, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

**Question**

If an object free falls let's say off a cliff that is 3 meters high, clearly it increases velocity and if at the bottom of the three meter there was a bucket full of jelly which created a retarding force in which the object stops 1 meters in and if the object is 5kg, why wouldn't the following work?

a) Find Velocity right before hitting jelly

b)Then find out deceleration value inside of jelly

c) do Acceleration*5kg=Force

Because if I find velocity right before it falls into the jelly- $V_{before}$, then use that in $V_f^2=V_{before}^2+(2*a*\Delta{x})$, wouldn't that find the deceleration in the jelly?

*What my friend suggested-*

So I asked this to my friend and he said that I should set the $mgh$ on top of cliff compared work and solve for the force. Why is that supposed to work but not my way?

Answer (score 1):

Both methods will work. It's not uncommon that there are more than one different approaches to a problem and you can choose whatever method seems most convenient.

For example consider the initial drop from rest at height $h$ down to the surface of the jelly. The PE change is $-mgh$ and since the total energy is conserved that means the kinetic energy must have increased by $+mgh$, so we get:

$$ \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 = mgh $$

or:

$$ v^2 = 2gh $$

which is exactly the same as your kinematic formula (with $v_i = 0$). So both methods give the same velocity.

In the case of the passage through the jelly you could once again use either method, but given you know $v_i$, $v_f = 0$ and $s = 1$m I would simply use your kinematic formula. That seems the quickest and simplest approach to me.

As a footnote: you're assuming the deceleration in the jelly is constant and for a real jelly that wouldn't be the case. You'd probably get something like [quadratic drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Drag_at_high_velocity) i.e. $a \propto v^2$.